# load a satellite assembly resource file

Tags: c#, .net, globalization

I am trying to load a different resources dll for various cultures. For ja-JP I place my resources.dll in a folder named ja and all works well. But what should the folder structure look like if I want to load say zh-Hans versus zh-Hant where the language code is the same but the region code differs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got in trouble with that before, name the folder ja-JP.  Similarly, the Chinese folders should be named zh-Hant and zh-Hans.  I'm partial to the latter.